# C++ shared_ptr copy constructor syntax

Tags: c++, syntax, reference, shared-ptr, copy-constructor

I have the following C++ code that I'm trying to get to compile (relevant sections follow).  I'm having trouble understanding what's wrong with my syntax.

I get the error

```
C2664: A(const A&) : cannot convert parameter 1 from A *const to const A&
```

As I understand it, the `*b.getA()` should dereference the pointer, giving me the actual object, which I should then be able to copy with the copy constructor.

```
class A: {
    public:
        A(const &A);
        A();
};

class B: {
    private:
        shared_ptr<A> myA;
    public:
        B() { myA = make_shared<A>(A()); }
        shared_ptr<A> getA() { return myA; }
};

main() {
    B b; // default constructor of B
    A a = *b.getA(); //try invoke copy constructor from A
    // Throws error C2664: A(const A&) : cannot convert parameter 1 from A *const to const A& 
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: -1 for posting a snippet full of syntax errors.

Comment: -1, Atleast post an compilable sample to save efforts of people who try to help you, `class A:`? Is that how you defined your class? Did it compile for you?

Comment: @Als, apologies. I naively felt that simplifying the class names would allow for greater clarity.  However, the not posting the compilable sample was the intention, because I was having an issue getting the syntax correct (I couldn't get it to compile, so was asking for help). The syntax was the question.

Comment: @Alex: Downvote removed. Please always post minimalistic compilable *real* code samples when you post questions in future, that helps everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your copy constructor is incorrect, it should be `A(const A&)` not `A(const &A)`.

This compiles fine:

```
class A {
    public:
        A(const A&){}
        A(){}
};

class B {
    private:
        shared_ptr<A> myA;
    public:
        B() { myA = make_shared<A>(); }
        shared_ptr<A> getA() { return myA; }
};

main() {
    B b; // default constructor of B
    A a = *b.getA();
}
```

Comment: `A a1 = *b.getA(); A a2 = *b.getA();` would that give me two different objects?

Answer (score 0):

`A(const &A);` is wrong. There are two correct and equivalent forms. These are

```
A(const A & /*name*/);
A(A const & /*name*/);
```